# Leave minimal tip

Tags: python, optimization, loss

If you need to pay a certain amount of money with different coins, calculating the exact number of coins to pay the amount is simple, you can use something like:

```
for i, j in zip(coins, needed): 
         if amount >= 2*i: 
             j = amount // i 
             amount = amount - j * i 
             print (i ," : ", j)
```

This works, if i need to pay 98 $, and I have 50, 10, 5 and 1 coins.

But what if I need to pay 98, but I do not have just 100, 50, 20 coins?
(the optimal solution would be to give a 100, and have 2 as loss)
Is there a simple platonic way to solve it? Or I need to compute all the different variations, and search for the minimal loss?

Comment: You don't need to compute *all* variations: once you have one way of solving for a given amount, you don't need any other ways of solving that amount.

Comment: @ScottHunter But how do I know that one solve is the optimal solution? For example 98 can't be payed exactly. But if you try to pay it as 50+20+20+20 that's worse than paying it as 100 or 50+50

Comment: Sounds like a homework to me... Okay, so you'll always need to pay *at most* your lowest coin-1. You can therefore search for solution for amount, amount+1... and so on but only until your first hit. As for solution for exact amount if you don't have all coins - dynamic programming, the case if already explained on many sites explaining dynamic programming. ;)

Comment: "Optimal" in terms of what?

Comment: [Obviously, those are only hints. I won't do your homework for you. And as I said, there are 2 things you need to do: 1) solution for exact amount for only some coins, 2) iterate for amount, amount+1... until first hit.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@h4z3 Thanks

One solution which works is, if anyone knows a shorter/better version anticipated thanks

```
d_amount = amount
x=0
while True:
    served_coins = []
    served_units = []
    for i, j in zip(coins, needed): 
         if d_amount >= i: 
             j = d_amount // i 
             d_amount = d_amount - j * i 
             served_coins.append(i)
             served_units.append(j)
    #print d_amount
    if (d_amount == 0):
        break
    else:
        x = x + 1
    d_amount = amount + x
```